# Angular js IE11 Bug - Invalid argument

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a bug in my angular project only happens in IE, see issue below:

```
Error: Invalid argument.
   at interpolateFnWatchAction (http://localhost:51051/scripts/angular.js:6898:19)
   at Scope.prototype.$digest (http://localhost:51051/scripts/angular.js:12395:23)
   at Scope.prototype.$apply (http://localhost:51051/scripts/angular.js:12660:13)
   at done (http://localhost:51051/scripts/angular.js:8272:34)
   at completeRequest (http://localhost:51051/scripts/angular.js:8477:7)
   at xhr.onreadystatechange (http://localhost:51051/scripts/angular.js:8416:11)
```

I have got some placeholders on some of the pages, I have tried removing them but the issue still happing.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: What code causes that error to be thrown

Comment: Good question,  I m not sure, what causes it.

Comment: Can you make a reduced test case on JSFiddle? Also, can you provide the code you're using that's causing the error? (Looks like, you're doing an `$http` request, and then you're trying to assign a scope variable in `success()`?)

Comment: Is there something inherently wrong with setting scope variables in a success callback?

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error in the following cases, both where the problem code was executing as part of the XHR callback:

1. setting $scope variables
2. using JQuery to perform DOM manipulations

I resolved 1 by moving/dropping the setting code to another code location, and 2 by wrapping the problem code in an angular $timeout call.